# Android gradle build with firebase dependency has warnings (ignoring httpclient)

Tags: java, android, gradle, firebase

In my Android project which use firebase the gradle build shows this annoying warning:

```
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for devDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

i tryed adding the exclude option on the build.gradle but i had no luck

```
compile ('com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.2.1') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1'   //IGNORED
    }
```

i also tryed removing the version like suggested but the warning remains

```
compile ('com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.2.1') {
        exclude group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'  //SAME
    }
```

Comment: Be sure to accept one of those answers to help others in the future. I realize you have a wait period to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the option to remove the warning

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken this should be

```
compile ('com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.2.1') {
        exclude group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'  
}
```

version can be omitted.

Comment: it looks the same as the other accepted answer but the warning is removed with the other syntax